# Commutative Rings and nilpotent

Tags: prime-numbers, integers

Here is some background information about the question I'm working on:

> If $A$ is a commutative ring, an element $a \in A$ is called *nilpotent* if $a \neq 0$ but $a^m = 0$ for some positive integer $m$.

My question is the following:

> Suppose that $n > 1$ is a positive integer which is *not* divisible by the square of any prime. Show that $\mathbb{Z_n}$ does not contain any nilpotent elements.

The question actually has two parts, but I solved the first part already.The first part of the question says to find an example of a nilpotent element in the ring $\mathbb{Z_8}$ and I chose $a = 4$ and $m = 2$. In $\mathbb{Z_8}$, $\bar 8 = \bar 0$. How can I extend what I know and apply it to my original question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be such that no square of a prime divides it, and consider the quotient map $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z_n$.  The kernel of the map is $n\mathbb Z$, the multiples of $n$, and so we can rephrase our problem as follows: Show that if $n|r^k$ for some $k$, then $n|r$.  This, in turn, can be shown by noting that, since no square of a prime divides $n$, $d$ divides $n$ if and only if $p|d$ for every prime $p$ such that $p|n$.

Comment: So is this enough to show that $\mathbb{Z_n}$ contains no nilpotent elements?

Comment: Yes, because if the image of $r$ ir $[r]$, then $[r]$ is nilpotent if and only if $[r]$ is non-zero but $[r]^k=[r^k]$ is zero, which is equivalent to $n\not| r$ but $n|r^k$.

Answer (score 1):

This is exercise $26$ [here](http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/oldwebpages/math331Fall2014/Final%20Exam%20Review%20Problems%20Solutions.pdf) on page $6$, together with a solution. Use $(c)$ and prove the claim.

Comment: The variables $m$ and $r$ are positive integers correct?

Comment: Actually, the exercise is to prove that certain rings contain nilpotents, not that certain rings don't.

Comment: @Aaron Right, but this is equivalent, as it turns out. If $p^2$ divides $n$ there is a nonzero nilpotent element, otherwise not.

Comment: It's somewhat of a slighter version of my question. Is the argument essentially the same ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Are you certain?  Neither the problem nor the solution imply iff, best as I can tell.

Comment: @Aaron You are right, the solution does not imply "iff", but it goes exactly the same way. You have done it in your answer (and this is a good answer anyway). The statement now is indeed "nonzero nilpotent elements *if and only if* $n$ is divisible by a square of a prime".